# show balance in simple atm in java

Tags: java, arrays, sum

This code models a simple ATM machine that can deposit, withdraw, and show the 10 latest transactions in an array of 10 index values.

My problem is that I can't get the balance right after 10 deposits, the balance only seems to sum the values in my array, not including the transactions made before those ten. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class cashier2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) 

        {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            int amount = 0;
            int choice = 0;
            int[] transactions = new int[10];
            int sum = 0;
            int balance = 0;

            while(choice != 4)
            {
                choice = menu();
                switch(choice)
                {
                case 1:
                    System.out.print("deposit");
                    sum = keyboard.nextInt();
                    if(sum == 0)
                    {
                        System.out.print("wrong amount");
                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        amount = (int) + sum;
                        makeTransactions(amount, transactions);
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.print("withdrawal ");
                    sum = keyboard.nextInt();
                    if(sum == 0)
                    {
                        System.out.print("wrong amount");
                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        amount = (int) - sum;
                        makeTransactions(amount, transactions);
                    }

                    break;
                case 3:
                    showTransactions(transactions, balance);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Exit");
                    break;

                }

            }

        }

            public static int menu()
            {
                Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
                int choice = 0;

                System.out.println("Simple atm");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("1. deposit");
                System.out.println("2. withdrawal");
                System.out.println("3. balance");
                System.out.println("4. exit");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("your choice: ");
                choice = keyboard.nextInt();
                return choice;
            }

            public static void showTransactions(int[] transactions, int balance)
            {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Tidigare transaktioner: ");
                System.out.println();

                for(int i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++)
                {
                    if(transactions[i] == 0)
                    {
                        System.out.print("");
                    }   
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.print(transactions[i] + "\n");
                        balance = balance + transactions[i];
                    }

                }
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Saldo: " + balance + " kr" + "\n");
                System.out.println();
            }

            public static void makeTransactions(int amount, int[] transactions)
            {
                int position = findNr(transactions);
                if (position == -1)
                {
                    moveTrans(transactions);
                        position = findNr(transactions);
                        transactions[position] = amount;
            }
                else
                {

                    transactions[position] = amount;
                }
            }       

            public static int findNr(int[] transactions)
            {
                int position = -1;

                for(int i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++)
                {
                    if (transactions[i] == 0)
                    {
                        position = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return position;
            }



            //}
            public static void moveTrans(int [] transactions)
            {
                        for(int i = 0; i < transactions.length-1; i++)
                        {

                                transactions[i] = transactions[i + 1];
                        }

                        transactions[transactions.length-1] = 0;

                    }
                }
```

Comment: This is the problem:`amount = (int) + sum;` You need to change the amount variable by using `amount = amount + sum`. The same can be said when you are withdrawing money.

Comment: So I shouldn't keep the amount=(int)+sum at all in my code?

Comment: Having a closer look at your code I realized, that you are only updating the balance when you are prompted by the user to show the balance, which is the source of the problem because your solution is restricted to only 10 transactions and if the user makes more, you are simply overriding the oldest transaction without it impact the balance and that's why you experience such problems.
Solution is to either update the balance after each transaction or update the balance with the value of the oldest transaction in the `moveTrans` method.

Comment: I see. And the problem is that I don't get my update right. I don't know where to put it in my code to make it right. I tried to do it in the makeTransactions method like this but that didn't work out as I thought it would.